# How can I replace the app id with the correct Property ID and save it without errors?

Tags: android

I confused put app id in Property ID in Admob Mediation on Waterfall source. I want to replace with property id again but cannot save it. How to solve it?

It first time for me. So i make this mistake hope everyone can help me❤️

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.